# Limiting a for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

So I'm having a small problem with a piece of my code, I have a system that is adding checkpoints to a program and I want it to add a checkpoint every 14 mins, but I also want to limit it to only add x amount of checkpoints based on how many hours a course as. So for an example, the first course has 12 hours so I only want 12 checkpoints created, but it's creating 16 based on the $time_in_secs, so that variable will always be different as its check the time between the start and end date of the program. For the second program, it has 24 hours but its creating 33 checkpoints and so on and so forth. $checkpoint_limit is what I want to limit the for loop by, but I still need it add the 840 as that is the time in seconds and I need a checkpoint created every 14 mins

I have done a few different things but none of them seemed to work. Tried setting a min() also tried doing an if but also does not seem to work.

```
$checkpoint_limit = (abs($numHours) * 3);
//840 = 14 minute interval * 60
for ($i = 840; $i < $time_in_secs; $i += 840) {
//Code here that adds the checkpoints
}
```

Comment: I'm not following. Can you share the code `//code here that adds checkpoints` and maybe give some examples of what one of these "courses" looks like and why you are looping to "set a checkpoint" when you know exactly how many checkpoints you want before you even begin your loop.... or do you?

Comment: What is `$time_in_secs`?

Comment: $time_in_secs is just the time between the start of the program and the end of the program

Comment: I need it to loop to add the checkpoints every 14 mins, each program will have a different amount of checkpoints based off of $time_in_secs, I want to limit the for loop with $checkpoint_limit but I dont seem to know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In for loop check for no of checkpoints created and if they exceed $checkpoint_limit then break the loop.

Try:

```
$checkpoint_limit = (abs($numHours) * 3);
$no_of_checkpoints = 0;
//840 = 14 minute interval * 60
for ($i = 840; $i < $time_in_secs; $i += 840) {
    //Code here that adds the checkpoints
    $no_of_checkpoints++;
    if($no_of_checkpoints > $checkpoint_limit){
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a second condition inside for loop with && operator.For example;

```
$j=0
for($i=840;$i<$timeInSecs && $j<12;$i +=840)
{
 //example code here
$j++
}
```

I am sorry for the low quality answer i am using SO mobile and could not manage to post the code.So j variable is like a checkpoint time.You have added 14 minute checkpoint and what i get is u want it to loop for a specific count you can do it with that way.And you should increase $j in the end of the for loop.